# Show that an integral operator with Bessel function kernel is bounded on $L^2(0,\infty)$

Tags: differential-equations, sp.spectral-theory, special-functions

Let $J_0$ denote the Bessel function of the first kind of order $\nu = 0$ (see [DLMF 10.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2)),
$$ 
J_0(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(\tfrac{1}{4} z^2)^k }{k! \Gamma(k + 1)}.
$$
Put $u_0(r) = r^{1/2}J_0(\sqrt{z}r)$, $r > 0$, where the branch of the square root is along the negative real axis, and we assume $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ belongs to the upper half plane. Furthermore, let $u_1(r) = H^{(1)}_0(\sqrt{z} r)$, where $H^{(1)}_0$ is the Bessel function of the third kind of order $\nu = 0$ (See [DLMF 10.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2) again).

Here, we have constructed $u_0$, $u_1$ so that $u_0 \sim r^{1/2}$ and $u_1 \sim r^{1/2} |\ln r|$ as $r \to 0$ and $|u_1| \sim e^{- \text{Im} \, \sqrt{z}}$ as $r \to \infty$. Furthermore, $u_0$ and $u_1$ are linearly independent solutions to the second order ODE
$$
(-\partial^2_r -\tfrac{1}{4r^2} - z)u = 0.
$$

> I would like to demonstrate by elementary methods that the "variation of parameters" formula
> $$
> L^2(0,\infty) \ni f \mapsto  u_1(r) \int^r_0  u_0(r') f(r') dr' +  u_0(r) \int_r^\infty  u_1(r') f(r') dr'
> $$
> Gives a bounded operator $L^2(0,\infty) \to L^2(0,\infty)$.

So far, I have tried using Schur's criterion, which means I need to show
$$ 
u_1(r) \int^r_0  u_0(r') dr' +  u_0(r) \int_r^\infty  u_1(r') dr'
$$
is bounded as $r \to \infty$. However, I'm having trouble controlling the first term, because while $u_1$ decays exponentially near infinity, $u_0$ may have exponential growth for large $r$ (see [DLMF 10.17.3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17)). Are there tricks of Bessel function asymptotics I am overlooking? Or maybe Schur's criterion is not the correct approach?

Comment: The way you tried works since the asymptotic decay at infinity of $u_1$ compensate exactly the growth of $u_0$. You have to use the precise asymptotics of Bessel functions. I can give a reference for similar computations, if you need.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you for your comment. Yes, if you could provide a reference that would be very helpful. Do you expect the Schur criterion would also work in the case $\nu > 0$, or is some other method necessary there?

Comment: You can have a look here https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.10314, Section 2 but I do not claim for originality (see also [16] in the references). Note that the computation is explicitely done in $L^2$ (with respect to the symmetrizing measure) but the same proof holds in $L^p$ and for more general measures. We deduced this last  from heat kenel estimates. The same works also for $\nu>0$, as in the paper above.